# $(shell) references in bash

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

Given the sample code form the [Simian project](https://github.com/google/simian) Makefile:

```
OSX_VERSION=$(shell sw_vers -productVersion 2>/dev/null | cut -d. -f1-2)
SWIG=$(shell type -p swig 2>/dev/null)
SIMIAN_VERSION=2.4
SIMIAN=simian-${SIMIAN_VERSION}
SDIST_TAR=dist/simian-${SIMIAN_VERSION}.tar
SDIST=${SDIST_TAR}.gz
MUNKI_VERSION=2.3.0.2519
MUNKI=munkitools-${MUNKI_VERSION}
MUNKIFILE=${MUNKI}.pkg
PYTHON_VERSION=2.6
PYTHON=$(shell type -p python${PYTHON_VERSION})
TS=$(shell date '+%s')
```

I've tried to follow the makefile steps manually, but 'shell' is not referenced in the [Makefile](https://github.com/google/simian/blob/master/Makefile), or in my path.  'shell' is also absent from inside the VE created by the project.

Where is $(shell) referenced from?

Comment: I should add, the Makefile works just fine, I'm trying to understand the underlying magic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(shell ...)` is a [built-in function in GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) which is equivalent to the backtick-construct in standard make. It expands to the output of the command specified as arguments.

Comment: Thanks, very concise!  could you add a reference link? I'll gladly accept if edited to include.

Comment: Added link to reference documentation.